# react redux dispatch to reducer in createslice not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-reducers

I friends,
I develop react redux toolkit slice everything ok but in function dispatch not working send to dispatchUserBlockingUpdate function in react-dom.development.js where is the my problem ?

I look changeProfitSortType function get data when need to send dispatch(changeProfitSort) not work !

This is: sortingSlice.js

```
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const sortingSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'sorting',
    initialState: {
        profitSortType: false,
    },
    reducers: {
        changeProfitSort: (state, action) => {
            state.profitSortType = action.payload;
            //return { ...state, profitSortType: action.payload }
        },
    },
});

export const { changeProfitSort } = sortingSlice.actions;

export const changeProfitSortType = (data) => async dispatch => {
    console.log(data);
    let status = data.status;
    console.log(status);
    await dispatch(changeProfitSort(status));
}

export default sortingSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `sortingSlice` is fine.

`changeProfitSort` is not an asynchronous function, so `await dispatch(changeProfitSort(status));` doesn't make sense.

You don't need the `changeProfitSortType` function at all.  You can just call `dispatch(changeProfitSort(data.status))` in your component instead of `dispatch(changeProfitSortType(data))`.

If the `data` is coming from an asynchronous function then you might want to use [`createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk).

Comment: Thank you for answer, I changed my codes and I delet async and await. But anything changed already not work :( my new codes export const sortingSlice = createSlice({ name: 'sorting', initialState: { profitSortType: false, }, reducers: { changeProfitSort: (state, action) => { state.profitSortType = action.payload; }, }, }); export const { changeProfitSort } = sortingSlice.actions; export const changeProfitSortType = (data) => dispatch => { dispatch(changeProfitSort(data)); }